# Translating text in Django without having to do it myself (physically typing into the django.py file)

Tags: python, django, translation

I have been researching how to translate my Django app into another language for some time now. I still cannot understand 1 thing (below).

I have been reading the documentation here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/translation/#internationalization-in-template-code

I am trying to figure out how to get translated text without having to type it myself in the django.po file.

```
#: /path/to/template
msgid "English Word"
msgstr ""  # <-- I have to type this myself for every word?
```

The msgstr has to be type in myself? Is there an easier way to literally translate this and place it in msgstr without actually having to type it in?

I am thinking of just creating a python script to hit some API that translates words and then place it in there somehow for me. Just wondering if there is an easier way to do this.

Comment: Unless you are using super-simple collection of words translations are not that straight forward, which is why you typically have a _translator_ do the translation work.  Having said that if you're translations are simple you could write a script to pull out translations for matching _msgid_ values in the existing [django code base](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/gis/locale/ja/LC_MESSAGES/django.po).  Looks they are nested within the codebase but it could be collected and matches made fairly easily.

Comment: Ah, I did not know a translator was used. I always thought it was some function already written that used google translate or something... thanks for the insight

Comment: You could do that, but yes, that's not a feature of the translations framework.  (_and without a qualified translator it would be hard to tell if the translations made were appropriate_)

Comment: Luckily my wife is ESL and it needs to be in Spanish, so I'm just gonna mark it all up and have her translate... Thanks again for the assistance